# Why are the elements of the std::multimap changing after exiting the loop in this code?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to implement a transparency in my OpenGL prorgam. Currently I have such function (minimal reproducible example):

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Sprite
{
public:
    std::vector<int> m_meshes;
    std::pair<float, float> pos;
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, Sprite> m_sprites = {
        { 0, { { 43 } } },
        { 1, { { 234 } } }
    };

    std::multimap<int, const Sprite*, std::greater<int>> translucentSprites{};
    for (const std::pair<int, Sprite>& spritePair : m_sprites)
    {
        translucentSprites.insert({ spritePair.second.pos.first + spritePair.second.pos.second, &spritePair.second});
        std::cout << translucentSprites.begin()->second->m_meshes.size() << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << translucentSprites.begin()->second->m_meshes.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

After running of this code, I get the following result:

```
1 1 0
```

The first two numbers are 1, but the third number for some reason is 0, not 1. I tried to use debugger, but it did not help. What is my mistake here?

Comment: What is `m_sprite`? Is `spritePair.second` something that will go out of scope immediately, and all pointers to it will be invalidated? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `const std::pair<int, Sprite>& spritePair` goes out of scope (in each iteration), the *copy* of the `Sprite` will be gone and the pointer will be dangling.

You can fix it by making it

```
const std::pair<const int, Sprite>& spritePair
```

which would then reference the actual `pair` in the map instead of creating a `std::pair<int, Sprite>` via conversion.

An alternative fix is to use structured bindings:

```cpp
for (const auto& [idx, sprite] : m_sprites) {
    translucentSprites.insert({sprite.pos.first + sprite.pos.second, &sprite});
```

A simplification could be to use `emplace` instead of `insert`:

```cpp
translucentSprites.emplace(sprite.pos.first + sprite.pos.second, &sprite);
```

Comment: The simpler-er fix is to use `auto` as `spritePair`'s type. The rest of the code can stay the same.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux :-) Sure, it would require less typing, but using `sprite` instead of `spritePair.second` makes it simpler to read.

Comment: Your answer is better. But as for "simpler " I guess it's a matter of perspective.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree and changed the wording and moved the simplification to `emplace` instead :-)

Comment: I understood. I thought that making entire pair const will prevent copying, but I needed to explicitly make the first element const as a key of unordered_map

Comment: @RomanLeshchuk Exactly, otherwise it'll create a temporary, that will have its life prolonged until the end of the scope for `spritePair` since it's bound by a `const&`. You wouldn't be able to bind to a non-`const` `std::pair<int, Sprite>&`- but with the proper type, you can.

Comment: @RomanLeshchuk To avoid a copy you need a reference, and a reference can only bind to an object of the exact right type. Otherwise, it tries to convert the object to the exact right type (which implies a copy).  The `value_type` of a `std::unordered_map<Key, T>` is `std::pair<const Key, T>` which is not exactly the same as `std::pair<Key, T>` (even if they are convertible).